# SSRS Chart Custom Legend

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a pie chart like this

[image]

However, I'd like it to look like this (i.e. left-aligned text, right aligned values within the label)

[image]

It doesn't seem possible in SSRS, which is a problem - can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is!

Right click your series group -> `Series Group Properties...`

Insert the appropriate calculations into the label expression.  I've done similar things like adding counts to the axis labels on bar charts.

EDIT: I feel like your best bet for these alignments is to create a small table next to the chart.  It's an awkward solution, but here's an example I threw together to show it can kinda be done.  You just have to make sure they are sorted the same.  You can use a group + dataset to get your values. It's a very brittle fix, but it works.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, that isn't really what I meant. I know I can edit the label, what I would like it left-aligned text, right aligned values as in the image above.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think this is possible.  Each one would need to resolve to a single expression, and you could only right/left align the whole expression.  I know it would be a hack, but if you always have the same 6 countries, you could place a small table with those calculations next to it.  Just make sure you sort them the same.

Comment: I haven't checked, but is there maybe a way to set the text to HTML formatting and use html tags to align the text?